# Can not remove item class for form custom validation

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to build a registration form, where free emails are not allowed, such as: (gmail|hotmail|yahoo|live|outlook|aol|iCloud|me|yandex|protonmail|gmx)

I wrote the code below, using regex for form validation, but the error message never disappeared!

Is my regex wrong, or is something wrong with my JS or CSS?

```js
// There are many ways to pick a DOM node; here we get the form itself and the email
// input box, as well as the span element into which we will place the error message.
const submit  = document.querySelector('.submit');

const email = document.getElementById('email');
const emailError = document.querySelector('span.error');

email.addEventListener('input', function (event) {
  // Each time the user types something, we check if the
  // form fields are valid.

  if (email.validity.valid) {
    // If there is an error message visible, if the field
    // is valid, we have removed the error message.
    emailError.textContent = ''; // Reset the content of the message
   // emailError.className = 'error'; // Reset the visual status of the message
    emailError.classList.remove('active');
  } else {
    // If there is still an error, show the correct error
    showError();
  }
});

submit.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  // if the email field is valid, we will let the form submit

  if(!email.validity.valid) {
    // If it isn't, we display an appropriate error message
    showError();
    // Then we prevent the form from being sent by canceling the event
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});

function showError() {
  if(email.validity.valueMissing) {
    // If the field is empty,
    // display the following error message:
    emailError.textContent = 'You need to enter an e-mail address.';
  } else if(email.validity.typeMismatch) {
    // If the field doesn't contain an email address,
    // display the following error message:
    emailError.textContent = 'Entered value needs to be an e-mail address.';
  } else if(email.validity.tooShort) {
    // If the data is too short,
    // display the following error message:
    emailError.textContent = `Email should be at least ${ email.minLength } characters; you entered ${ email.value.length }.`;
  }

  // Set the styling appropriately
  emailError.className = 'error active';
}
```

```css
body, div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, 
pre, form, fieldset, input, textarea, p, blockquote, th, td { 
  padding:0;
  margin:0;}

fieldset, img {border:0}

ol, ul, li {list-style:none}

:focus {outline:none}

body,
input,
textarea,
select {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #4c4c4c;
}

p {
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 18px;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #4c4c4c;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

html{
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.testbox {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 343px; 
  height: 464px; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px/7px; 
  -moz-border-radius: 8px/7px; 
  border-radius: 8px/7px; 
  background-color: #ebebeb; 
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.31); 
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.31); 
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.31); 
  border: solid 1px #cbc9c9;
}

input[type=radio] {
  visibility: hidden;
}

form{
  margin: 0 30px;
}

label.radio {
    cursor: pointer;
  text-indent: 35px;
  overflow: visible;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

label.radio:before {
  background: #3a57af;
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  top:2px;
  left: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

label.radio:after {
    opacity: 0;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0.5em;
    height: 0.25em;
    background: transparent;
    top: 7.5px;
    left: 4.5px;
    border: 3px solid #ffffff;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

input[type=radio]:checked + label:after {
    opacity: 1;
}

hr{
  color: #a9a9a9;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

input[type=email],input[type=password]{
  width: 200px; 
  height: 39px; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px/5px 5px 4px 4px; 
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px/0px 0px 4px 4px; 
  border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px/5px 5px 4px 4px; 
  background-color: #fff; 
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.09); 
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.09); 
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.09); 
  border: solid 1px #cbc9c9;
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-top: 13px; 
  padding-left: 10px;
}

input[type=password]{
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

#icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: #3a57af;
  padding: 8px 0px 8px 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px; 
  -moz-border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px; 
  border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px;
  color: white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.09);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.09); 
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.09); 
  border: solid 0px #cbc9c9;
}

.gender {
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.accounttype{
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

a.submit {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: white;
  padding: 6px 25px 0px 20px;
  margin: 10px 8px 20px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 50px; height: 27px; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
  -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
  border-radius: 5px; 
  background-color: #3a57af; 
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px rgba(58,87,175,.75); 
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px rgba(58,87,175,.75); 
  box-shadow: 0 3px rgba(58,87,175,.75);
  transition: all 0.1s linear 0s; 
  top: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

a.button:hover {
  top: 3px;
  background-color:#2e458b;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none; 
  -moz-box-shadow: none; 
  box-shadow: none;
  
}
/*
input:invalid:required {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, pink, lightgreen);
}
*/

/* This is the style of our error messages */
.error {
  width  : 100%;
  padding: 0;

  font-size: 80%;
  color: white;
  background-color: #900;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;

  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.error.active {
  padding: 0.3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="testbox">
  <h1>Registration</h1>

  <form action="/" novalidate>
      <hr>
    <div class="accounttype">
      <input type="radio" value="None" id="radioOne" name="account" checked/>
      <label for="radioOne" class="radio" chec>Personal</label>
      <input type="radio" value="None" id="radioTwo" name="account" />
      <label for="radioTwo" class="radio">Company</label>
    </div>
  <hr>
  <label id="icon" for="name"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></label>
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" 
    pattern="/[\w\-\.]+@(?!(gmail|hotmail|yahoo|live|outlook|aol|iCloud|me|yandex|protonmail|gmx))[\w\.]+$/gm" 
    required/>
    <span class="error" aria-live="polite"></span>
 
   <p>By clicking Register, you agree on our <a href="#">terms and condition</a>.</p>
   <a href="#" class="submit">Register</a>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Why have you used `?!` in regex. This is negative look ahead. Don't you want your mail to end with the domain you've specified?

Comment: @decpk No, I donut want the email to have the domains I specified.

Comment: i have updated my answer, you could give it a try

Comment: @decpk how did you made the Regex chart in your answer?

Comment: @HasanAYousef [Regulex](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. the `/` should not be included in `pattern` attr. so we would not able to specify `im` option after '/', the pattern string is compiled with `ignoreCase` option by default
2. `email.validity.patternMismatch` was not handled in `showError`

Here is the proper [Regulex](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=i&re=%5E%5B%5Cw%5C-%5C.%5D%2B%40(%3F!(gmail%7Chotmail%7Cyahoo%7Clive%7Coutlook%7Caol%7CiCloud%7Cme%7Cyandex%7Cprotonmail%7Cgmx))%5Cw%2B(%5C.%5Cw%2B)%2B%24)

[image]

```js
// There are many ways to pick a DOM node; here we get the form itself and the email
// input box, as well as the span element into which we will place the error message.
const submit  = document.querySelector('.submit');

const email = document.getElementById('email');
const emailError = document.querySelector('span.error');

email.addEventListener('input', function (event) {
  // Each time the user types something, we check if the
  // form fields are valid.
  // console.log(email.validity);
  if (email.validity.valid) {
    // In case there is an error message visible, if the field
    // is valid, we remove the error message.
    emailError.textContent = ''; // Reset the content of the message
   // emailError.className = 'error'; // Reset the visual state of the message
    emailError.classList.remove('active');
  } else {
    // If there is still an error, show the correct error
    showError();
  }
});

submit.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  // if the email field is valid, we let the form submit

  if(!email.validity.valid) {
    // If it isn't, we display an appropriate error message
    showError();
    // Then we prevent the form from being sent by canceling the event
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});

function showError() {
  if(email.validity.valueMissing) {
    // If the field is empty,
    // display the following error message.
    emailError.textContent = 'You need to enter an e-mail address.';
  } else if(email.validity.typeMismatch) {
    // If the field doesn't contain an email address,
    // display the following error message.
    emailError.textContent = 'Entered value needs to be an e-mail address.';
  } else if (email.validity.patternMismatch) {
    // pattern match failed
    emailError.textContent = 'Entered value needs to be an e-mail address.';
    for (let p of 'gmail|hotmail|yahoo|live|outlook|aol|iCloud|me|yandex|protonmail|gmx'.split('|')) {
      if (email.value.indexOf('@'+p) !== -1) {
        emailError.textContent = 'Your email provider is not supported.';
        break;
      }
    } 
  } else if(email.validity.tooShort) {
    // If the data is too short,
    // display the following error message.
    emailError.textContent = `Email should be at least ${ email.minLength } characters; you entered ${ email.value.length }.`;
  }

  // Set the styling appropriately
  emailError.className = 'error active';
}
```

```css
body, div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, 
pre, form, fieldset, input, textarea, p, blockquote, th, td { 
  padding:0;
  margin:0;}

fieldset, img {border:0}

ol, ul, li {list-style:none}

:focus {outline:none}

body,
input,
textarea,
select {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #4c4c4c;
}

p {
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 18px;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #4c4c4c;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

html{
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.testbox {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 343px; 
  height: 464px; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px/7px; 
  -moz-border-radius: 8px/7px; 
  border-radius: 8px/7px; 
  background-color: #ebebeb; 
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.31); 
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.31); 
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.31); 
  border: solid 1px #cbc9c9;
}

input[type=radio] {
  visibility: hidden;
}

form{
  margin: 0 30px;
}

label.radio {
    cursor: pointer;
  text-indent: 35px;
  overflow: visible;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

label.radio:before {
  background: #3a57af;
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  top:2px;
  left: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

label.radio:after {
    opacity: 0;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0.5em;
    height: 0.25em;
    background: transparent;
    top: 7.5px;
    left: 4.5px;
    border: 3px solid #ffffff;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

input[type=radio]:checked + label:after {
    opacity: 1;
}

hr{
  color: #a9a9a9;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

input[type=email],input[type=password]{
  width: 200px; 
  height: 39px; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px/5px 5px 4px 4px; 
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px/0px 0px 4px 4px; 
  border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px/5px 5px 4px 4px; 
  background-color: #fff; 
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.09); 
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.09); 
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.09); 
  border: solid 1px #cbc9c9;
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-top: 13px; 
  padding-left: 10px;
}

input[type=password]{
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

#icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: #3a57af;
  padding: 8px 0px 8px 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px; 
  -moz-border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px; 
  border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px;
  color: white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.09);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.09); 
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.09); 
  border: solid 0px #cbc9c9;
}

.gender {
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.accounttype{
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

a.submit {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: white;
  padding: 6px 25px 0px 20px;
  margin: 10px 8px 20px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 50px; height: 27px; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
  -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
  border-radius: 5px; 
  background-color: #3a57af; 
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px rgba(58,87,175,.75); 
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px rgba(58,87,175,.75); 
  box-shadow: 0 3px rgba(58,87,175,.75);
  transition: all 0.1s linear 0s; 
  top: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

a.button:hover {
  top: 3px;
  background-color:#2e458b;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none; 
  -moz-box-shadow: none; 
  box-shadow: none;
  
}
/*
input:invalid:required {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, pink, lightgreen);
}
*/

/* This is the style of our error messages */
.error {
  width  : 100%;
  padding: 0;

  font-size: 80%;
  color: white;
  background-color: #900;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;

  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.error.active {
  padding: 0.3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="testbox">
  <h1>Registration</h1>

  <form action="/" novalidate>
      <hr>
    <div class="accounttype">
      <input type="radio" value="None" id="radioOne" name="account" checked/>
      <label for="radioOne" class="radio" chec>Personal</label>
      <input type="radio" value="None" id="radioTwo" name="account" />
      <label for="radioTwo" class="radio">Company</label>
    </div>
  <hr>
  <label id="icon" for="name"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></label>
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" 
    pattern="^[\w\-\.]+@(?!(gmail|hotmail|yahoo|live|outlook|aol|iCloud|me|yandex|protonmail|gmx))\w+(\.\w+)+$" 
    required/>
    <span class="error" aria-live="polite"></span>
 
   <p>By clicking Register, you agree on our <a href="#">terms and condition</a>.</p>
   <a href="#" class="submit">Register</a>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You should describe what is the "little problem" and how you changed it. Nevertheless, if you run the code and test it, you do not get the desired behaviour (that is, show an error message if the field contains one of the strings gmail, etc.), since, for example, it will validate addresses like abc@gmail.com or even abc@gmail.

Comment: mm, there is some thing wrong, if entered `x@gmail` it give correct input!

Comment: Thanks, but still accepting the email if there is no `.` at all, for example, `x@email` is considered a valid email!